# Exclude a selector in div

Tags: jquery

I've got a div that I want to enable a click function on, but not the "a" tags inside the div or the div it's toggling:

**HTML**

```
 <div class='row client-outstandings'>
  <div class='twelve columns'>
    <div class='panel'>
      <h3><a href="{% url clients.views.view_client c.client.id %}" target="_blank">{{ c.client }}</a> - {{ c.total|currency }}</h3>
      <div class='client-outstandings-details' style='display:none;'><a href="">Blah blah</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
$(function () {

    $('.client-outstandings').live('click', function () {
        $(this).find('.client-outstandings-details').toggle('fade');
    });

});
```

I'm trying to make it so any "a" tags inside the ".client-oustandings" div or ".client-outstandings-details" do not trigger the toggle.

Any ideas?

Comment: your question is not clear please make it clear

Comment: you cant see what triggers because your a tag is inside the div tag

Comment: use .on instead of .live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`live` method is deprecated you can use `on` method instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.client-outstandings', function () {
```

For preventing the event from bubbling, you can use `stopPropagation` method:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

Note that for delegating the event using `on` method, you should use a static parent element(*which is better*) or document object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('.client-outstandings').live('click', function () {
    $(this).find('.client-outstandings-details').toggle('fade');
});

$('.client-outstandings a').live('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return true;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpXty/5/).

But I recommend you to use `on`. Using `on` the code is

```
$(document).on('click', '.client-outstandings', function () {
    $(this).find('.client-outstandings-details').toggle('fade');
});

$('.client-outstandings').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return true;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpXty/4/).

Comment: changed it to on using your code i get: Uncaught ReferenceError: stopPropagation is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like below:

**HTML**

```
<div class='row client-outstandings'>
  <div class='twelve columns'>
    <div class='panel'>
      <h3><a href="{% url clients.views.view_client c.client.id %}" target="_blank">{{ c.client }}</a> - {{ c.total|currency }}</h3>
      <a href="" class="outstandingsAnchor">Blah blah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.outstandingsAnchor', toggle(function() {(
       $(this).wrap('<div class="client-outstandings-details" />');
    }, function() {
       $(this).unwrap();
   )};
});
```